# AttributeError: object has no attribute - although class method exists

Tags: python-3.x, class, attributeerror

I have a class consisting of 14 methods. Here is the skeleton:

```py
class Field
    def __init__():
        ...
        return

    def ...():

country = Field()
country.re_fitness_population()
```

It's a large class, so here is the full [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Sxf89y6B).

Running this code results in:

```
----> 1 country.re_fitness_population()

AttributeError: 'Field' object has no attribute 're_fitness_population'
```

Running `dir()` on this class doesn't show the method as available, and I've tried fixing any spacing issues, but running `python3 -tt` also doesn't show anything. I've tried renaming the method, also doesn't help.

I clearly have written the function as one of the methods of the class. I feel like there is something big I'm missing.

Comment: Does dir() show the rest of the methods?

Comment: It is weird if the method was correctly declared in the class. But without a [mcve] I am not able to reproduce, so I cannot help...

Comment: @AlanWilliams yes, dir() shows other methods, except `re_fitness_path` and `re_fitness_population`

Comment: @KomronAripov I copied your code, and my python seems to find it. (It does give me `TypeError: re_fitness_population() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)` though.)

Comment: I've got the same result as @AlanWilliams. It seems like something is wrong with your working environment.